# Can anybody get a visa for Azerbaijan from Batumi, Georgia now?

Tags: visas, georgia-country, consulates, azerbaijan, batumi

["Note you can't get an Azerbaijan visa in Batumi any more."](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/19033/is-any-southeast-asian-country-easier-for-obtaining-a-visa-for-china?noredirect=1#comment159384_19033) – chx

Is it just Australians who can no longer get their Azeri visa there, or everybody?

Also, why?

- Did the consulate in Batumi close down?
- Did it move to another city?
- Did Georgia-Azerbaijan relations sour?

Answer (score 2):

When I commented I have worked from memory based on the first report on http://caravanistan.com/visa/azerbaijan/ which said:

> June 2014: no more visas in Batumi! Earlier in June they did not offer visas without LOI, now it seems they do not hand out  visas at all anymore.

So my comment was outdated because some time after that report there were reports of success and failure both.

Comment: Interesting. Let's see what kind of info others can find.

Comment: Hi @chx. Are you still coming to Prague in Jan?